# reload a div without refreshing site

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, css

I have a div `#rightcontent` in 
a file data.php, that loads the data and echo it using css.css
I have an option in javascript called `updatedcontent();` that updates the db using ajax.

I want it to reload  the div with `id="rightcontent"` without reloading the whole page since it contains a whole lot of information. 
I was reading up on `load();` in http://api.jquery.com/load/ but all the implementations I tried failed. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

```
var fe = jQuery.noConflict();
function updatedw (name,spid,unum,rdid) {
document.getElementById('added').innerHTML += '<a href="#viewsp_'+spid+'" data-   tooltip="'+unum+'" id="pointer_div">'+name+'</a> <a href="?delete='+rdid+'" class="delete"    style="float:right"><img src="images/close.png" /></a><br> ';
fe('div#rightcontent').load('viewscreenplays.php');
}

fe("#clickme").click(function(){
    $("p.added").slideDown();
  });
fe(document).ready(function() {
  fe('a.delete').click(function(e) {
      fe(this).slideUp(300,function() {
          parent.remove();
        });
```

Comment: code added let me know if you have any idea

Answer (score 1):

It's up to you how you trigger the function, but you could try something like this:

```
function pop_rightcontent()
{
    $.post("backend_script.php", { var1: value1, var2: value2 }, pop_rightcontent_handler, "html");
}

function pop_rightcontent_handler(data)
{
    $("#rightcontent").html(data);
}
```

That should give you a starting point for your script.

Comment: this has nothing to do with what I asked for unfortunately

Comment: So even doing a simple `$("#rightcontent").load("your_page.html");` doesn't work?

Comment: @fogsy: You didn't have much in your question for anyone to go on when I answered it either.  I had to guess what you were doing.

Answer (score 0):

Either you'll have to populate the text inside that `div` with a combination of JavaScript and AJAX, collecting the data from a PHP file.

Or you'll have to put the `div` within a separate page and load it via an `iframe` so that the frame can be reloaded.

The first option is the most elegant... and better. Please don't use an `iframe`.